# How to hide the alert-danger in FormIO?

Tags: angular, formio

I'am using FormIO in Angular 7 and I don't want to display the alert-danger (the first) who contains "Societe est obligatoire" in my form if it's not valid.

[image]

this is my form declared in form-io.component.ts

```
form= {
components: [
  {
      type: "textfield",
      input: true,
      tableView: true,
      inputType: "text",
      inputMask: "",
      label: "Societe",
      key: "societe",
      placeholder: "societe",
      multiple: false,
      defaultValue: "",
      protected: false,
      unique: false,
      persistent: true,
      validate: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 1,
          pattern: "",
          custom: "",
          customPrivate: false
      },
      conditional: {
          show: "",
          when: null,
          eq: ""
      }
  },
  {
    input:true,
    label:"Validate",
    tableView:false,
    key:"ValidateFournisseur",
    size:"md",
    block:false,
    action:"submit",
    disableOnInvalid:true,
    theme:"primary",
    type:"button",   
    hidden:false 
  }
```

and this is my form-io.component.html

```
<formio [form]="form"></formio>
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you provide a demo code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who still looking for the answer

in your html

```
<formio [form]="form" [options]="options" ></formio>
```

and in yout ts file

```
options: Object = {
  submitMessage: "",
  disableAlerts: true,
  noAlerts: true
}
```

Hope it helps